# Will @reply in deleted answer appear in user's inbox?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, deleted-answers, global-inbox

I've read the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) on the matter, and searched for dupes, but haven't found an answer to this question:

If I @reply to a comment on my answer, and subsequently (immediately) delete my answer, will they still see the message in their inbox?

Does the presence of @user change the answer, versus an implicit notification when they were the only other user to comment on my post?

Does their in/ability to see the deleted answer as 10k make a difference for the notification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if you're a regular user. The notification goes away when the post is deleted.

If you're a moderator, the owner of that post *will* receive a notification if you commented on the post less than 1 hour prior to the post being deleted, or if you post the comment on an already deleted post. (I am not sure if this is true for @ replies to someone who is *not* the post owner).

But the answer is no for regular users.

Comment: The time limit does exist for comments made prior to deletion (or at least other posts say it does, but I thought it was 30 minutes). There's no time limit for notifications for comments made after deletion (tested this on a post deleted 6 years ago). I've definitely tested that moderator comments posted shortly prior to post deletion do create a notification which is *not* removed upon deletion of the post. I thought I'd seen another post say that limit was 30 minutes, but I haven't tested as to how long prior to post deletion the moderator's comment can be made and retain the notification.