# Deleting answers, reloading pages, and changing focus

Tags: feature-request, bug, sorting, information-display, deleted-posts

This question is closely related to the [recent changes in answer sort ordering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376062/280545), but I think it’s different enough (or niche enough) to warrant its own question.

Here is the workflow:

1. Be a moderator
2. Sort questions by “most recently changed,” because old, stable answers are less likely to need moderator attention
3. Discover an answer which needs to be deleted *and* interacted with in some way. For example, a [post-deletion comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231203/280545), or clicking on the username to visit their profile.
4. Delete the answer.

Now, sometimes deleting the answer instantly adds the pink background but doesn’t otherwise change the display of the page. In that case I can just click the "add a comment" link or the username or whatever other interaction I’m planning.
But other times, the freshly-deleted answer gets covered with a notice “this answer has been deleted, click to refresh the page,” which blocks the next thing I want to do.  (I think the difference is whether I click the deletion link under the answer or the deletion button in the flag toolbar, but I can never remember which one does which.)

I feel like, prior to the aforementioned [recent sorting changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376062/280545), reloading the page still tended to give me a page where the freshly-deleted answer was still shown in my browser window — that is, the page reloaded to the middle, where I had just been looking.  However, now that deleted answers are sorted to the bottom, the page reloads to the middle, but the answer I just deleted is no longer there.  Instead it has been sorted to the bottom, and I have to scroll around to find it again.

That’s my complaint.  If I’ve just deleted an answer, and you’re going to make me reload the page, the reloaded page should still show me the answer I just deleted, not some now-random place in the middle of the page.

Comment: I’m thinking inconsistently forcing you to  reload the page for no apparent reason is the problem here, not that deleted answers are consistently sorted to the bottom of the page. I did [ask for a way to sort deleted answers in with visible answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376115/2734940) instead of pushing them all to the bottom, but it was out of scope.

Comment: Given that you've said you can't remember which reloads the page: The banner "this answer has been deleted, **click to refresh the page**" does exactly what it says when you click it: it refreshes/reloads the page. It's possible to write a userscript to change that to just reloading the post, but SE broke `StackExchange.realtime.reloadPosts()` early in March, so it's a bit more complex. Note, however, that doing a live reload on the deleted post won't work if the user doesn't have the ability to view deleted posts.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for your comment. I would need an unreasonable amount of effort to write such a userscript, though I might be able to install one. As for viewing deleted posts, note that the first step in the workflow is "be a moderator."